# Schedule a rule to repeat every week at specific time not working

Tags: 7, rules

I am sooo close to getting this to work, but cannot figure out why I cannot get my rule to repeat. It's driving me nuts.

I created a component that has an action item to generate send a newsletter using the simplenews module. It works just fine when I execute it manually, but I need this to repeat weekly.

I've read a ton about having it repeat by using the action "Schedule component evaluation" and this makes total sense, but it just isn't firing after the initial rule. Right now I am testing it with +2 minutes so that I can see if it works or not. Eventually I want to have it be +1 week. But if it's not working with 2 minutes it won't work with 1 week.

EDIT: Right now I am running cron manually to check to see if it's working and it's just not.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that for some reason having such a short interval was the problem. After I extended it to +10 minutes it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running `cron` on demand to force your process to run every those 2 minutes, the way rules scheduler works is to create a [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) process that checks the dates:

```
function rules_scheduler_cron() {
  // Limit adding tasks to 1000 per cron run.
  $result = db_select('rules_scheduler', 'r', array('fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    ->fields('r')
    ->condition('date', time(), '<=')
    ->range(0, 1000)
    ->execute();

  $queue = DrupalQueue::get('rules_scheduler_tasks');
  foreach ($result as $task) {
    // Add the task to the queue and remove the entry afterwards.
    if ($queue->createItem($task)) {
      db_delete('rules_scheduler')
        ->condition('tid', $task['tid'])
        ->execute();
      $task_created = TRUE;
    }
  }

  if (!empty($task_created)) {
    // hook_exit() is not invoked for cron runs, so register it as shutdown
    // callback for logging the rules log to the watchdog.
    drupal_register_shutdown_function('rules_exit');
    // Clear the log before running tasks via the queue to avoid logging
    // unrelated logs from previous cron-operations.
    RulesLog::logger()->clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks pcambra. I tried manually running cron to be able to see if it was working and it wouldn't even work after I did that. So I am still baffled as to why this isn't working.

Comment: Could you provide the export of the rule? Also checking the rules_scheduler table would be something to do in case you've got issues there.

Comment: Well this is crazy, but maybe I was running it too fast. I change it to +10 minutes and it seems to be working now. Don't know why that is, but glad its working! By the way, your function above is giving me a white screen of death when the rule runs. Any idea why?

Comment: The function I pasted above is exactly what rules scheduler executes every time cron runs, many things can cause a WSOD, but memory limits is the top #1 probability, check https://www.drupal.org/node/158043